# rtcwake only using tomorrow if time is passed

Tags: suspend, cron

my server goes to sleep after 30 minutes idle. And I need to wake up my server every day at 3am. So far I use the following cron entry:

```
@reboot /usr/sbin/rtcwake -m no -u -t $(date +\%s -d `tomorrow 03:00`)
```

Works general fine with one exception. If the server boots between 00:00 and 03:00 (if used or activated by a client) the wake up time is set to the next day, the server is sent to idle before 03:00 and the planned job on 03:05 is not started.

How can I use rtcwake to set the wake up time to the next time it will be 03:00, meaning between 00:00 and 03:00 of a day the wake up should be set to 03:00 the current day and after 03:00 it should be set to 03:00 at the next day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following crontab entry should do what you want:

```
@reboot /usr/sbin/rtcwake -m no -u -t $(date +\%s -d "$(date +\%D -d '3 hours ago') +1 day +3 hours")
```

First, we subtract 3 hours from the current datetime and only keep the date:

```
$(date +\%D -d '3 hours ago')
```

...which will result in either today (if it's already past 3:00) or yesterday at 00:00:00.

Adding 1 day and 3 hours:

```
$(date +\%s -d "[...] +1 day +3 hours")
```

...will therefore result in either tomorrow 3:00 (if it's already past 3:00) or today 3:00.